# Get relation count through another relation?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have the following Prisma schema:

```
model Category {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  title       String
  description String
  deleted     DateTime?
  subforums   Subforum[]
}

model Subforum {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  categoryId  Int
  parentId    Int?
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  title       String
  description String
  deleted     DateTime?
  threads     Thread[]
  children    Subforum[]  @relation("ChildSubforums")
  category    Category    @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  parent      Subforum?   @relation("ChildSubforums", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
}

model Thread {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId   String
  subforumId Int
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt
  title      String
  content    String
  deleted    DateTime?
  posts      Post[]
  author     User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  subforum   Subforum  @relation(fields: [subforumId], references: [id])
}

model Post {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId  String
  threadId  Int
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
  content   String
  deleted   DateTime?
  author    User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  thread    Thread    @relation(fields: [threadId], references: [id])
}
```

And I'm trying to build an object like this:

```
interface Subforum {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    threads: number;
    posts: number;
}

interface Category {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    subforums: Subforum[]
}

const categories: Category[] = getCategories();
```

So far, I can get the Categories, subforums and thread's count for each subforum. Either way, I can't find a way to get the post count for each Subforum and to select just certain fields for the Categories. This is my current `getCategories` function:

```
export async function getCategories() {
  const categories = await db.category.findMany({
    where: {
      deleted: {
        equals: null,
      },
    },
    include: {
      subforums: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          title: true,
          _count: {
            select: {
              threads: true,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  return categories;
}
```

How can I modify my `getCategories` function (and schema, if needed) to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to modify your Prisma schema to include the post count in the Subforum model.

   ```
   model Subforum {
       // ... (other fields)
       // Add this field to count posts
       postsCount  Int?
       // ... (relations and other fields)
   }
   ```
2. You can modify the function to include the post count for each Subforum and to select specific fields for the Categories. Here's how you can achieve that:

   ```
   export async function getCategories() {
       const categories = await db.category.findMany({
          where: {
              deleted: {
                  equals: null,
              },
          },
          select: {
              id: true,
              title: true,
              subforums: {
                  select: {
                  id: true,
                  title: true,
                  _count: {
                      select: {
                          threads: true,
                          posts: true,  // Include post count
                      },
                  },
              },
           },
       },
   });
   return categories;
   }
   ```

Comment: Does that postsCount field gets updated every time a post is created for that thread in that specific subforum?

Comment: No, It won't.

You would need to manually update this field whenever a new post is created or deleted in a thread associated with that Subforum.

If you want to keep the postsCount field automatically up-to-date without manual intervention, you'll need to implement a mechanism to increment and decrement the postsCount value whenever a new post is created or deleted for a specific Subforum. This typically involves using database triggers, background jobs, or some other form of event-driven mechanism to ensure the count stays accurate.